# JRRuntimeException: net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JRException: Error opening input stream from URL

Tags: java, spring-boot, jasper-reports

**Update**

I have seen those "duplicate" answers and accepted one too. I tried those ways but it didn't help me with my issue.

So, to resolve this, I have used an external resource path which points to my .jrxm (.jasper for subreports) files. Now it is resolved.

This question is not a duplicate of [Jasper: error opening input stream from url](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8340874/jasper-error-opening-input-stream-from-url) and [Warning while Running report: Found two components for namespace](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17670456/warning-while-running-report-found-two-components-for-namespace).

In my jasper report, there are several subreports which will conditionally be printed.

When I run the project locally, I can download and view the report with no error. But when running on a remote server as a `.war` file, it gives this error:

**Warning**:

> Found two components for namespace
>   http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports/components

**Error:**

```
Caused by: net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JRException: Error opening input stream from URL : file:/opt/tigerhrm/tigerhrm-client/target/tigerhrmclient-beta-1.3.0.war!/WEB-INF/classes!/report-templates/employee-details/empWiseContactReport.jasper
        at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.util.JRLoader.getInputStream(JRLoader.java:348)
        at net.sf.jasperreports.repo.DefaultRepositoryService.getInputStream(DefaultRepositoryService.java:132)
        ... 80 more
Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: /opt/tigerhrm/tigerhrm-client/target/tigerhrmclient-beta-1.3.0.war!/WEB-INF/classes!/report-templates/employee-details/empWiseContactReport.jasper (No such file or directory)
        at java.io.FileInputStream.open0(Native Method)
```

I am setting the file path like this from the controller:

```
 String jasperResourcePath = request.getServletContext().getRealPath("/WEB-INF/");
 InputStream reportInputStream = getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("report-templates/attendance.jrxml");
```

> //note that, all the subreportes are linked as jasper  directly from
>   master report i.e
>   `<subreportExpression><![CDATA[$P{reportLocation} + "empWiseContactReport.jasper"]]></subreportExpression>`

Project Structure:

[image: Project Structure]

In my `.war` file, I have checked the jasper file path using a java-decompiler like this:

[image: path in war file:]

So, although the path is shown correctly in the .war file, why does it give this error? Any suggestions would be welcome.

Comment: Have you found the solution already?

Comment: yes, please check my update/edit in the question above